# UITableView how to select a row in edit mode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tvos

I am porting one of my iOS apps to tvOS.

On iOS, I have a tableview which is selectable in edit mode. On tvOS even if it has the option 'Single Selection during editing' (    _tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;), I cannot select any row (neither on simulator nor on device).

The cell is of Basic type. Maybe because the cell has not any focusable component?

Any idea?

Thx

Comment: Single selection during editing uses the `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` property.

Comment: Yes, right! I actually used allowsSelectionDuringEditing but it doesn't help

Comment: You've definitely set the .delegate?

Comment: Maybe instead of selecting the row, there is a delegate for didEnterFocus or something

Comment: I have tried both -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canFocusRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath and -(BOOL)canBecomeFocused in a custom cell but nothing has worked so far

Answer (score 1):

I just talked to an Apple engineer at a tech talk, and it sounds like something that was left out of the current version of tvOS, either by accident or because it was considered an uncommon use case. The engineer suggested filing a bug report if this is something where there isn't a good alternative in your app from a UX perspective.

Comment: I've just run into this same bug in tvOS 10. Nuts.